# Trying to change cross-fade-all effect to a slide effect in core-animated-pages componenet

Tags: polymer

I have core-animated-pages element in my polymer-element:

```
<link rel="import" href="../public/components/core-animated-pages/core-animated-pages.html">

<polymer-element name="welcom-arrow" attributes="counter">
<template>
<style>

</style>
<core-animated-pages transitions="cross-fade-all" selected="{{welcomPage}}">
  <section>
    <div class="blueBackground">
      <h1>asd</h1>
      <h3>asdasdasdn</h3>
      <paper-button on-tap="{{Foward}}">
        Keep Going
        <core-icon icon="forward"></core-icon>
      </paper-button>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="blueBackground">
      welcom 2
    </div>
  </section>
</core-animated-pages>
</template>
<script>
Polymer({
  welcomPage: 0,
  Foward: function() {
    this.welcomPage++;
  },
  Backward: function() {
    this.welcomPage--;
  }
});
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

my cross-fade-all transition works perfectly but when I want to change it to a slide effect by swapping the `cross-fade-all` attribute to `slide-from-right` the effect is not working. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to import the transition itself.

```
<link rel="import" href="../public/components/core-animated-pages/transitions/slide-from-right.html">
```

And now you can change your transition

```
<core-animated-pages transitions="slide-from-right" selected="{{welcomPage}}">
```

The reason why the previous transition worked, is because `core-animated-pages` already import it.

Hope it helped !